# Was it Mordechai or Kish that was exiled?

Tags: megillat-esther, mordechai, babylonian-exile

Seemingly, from reading the pasuk in the megillah;

> Esther 2:6
> אֲשֶׁר הׇגְלָה מִירוּשָׁלַיִם עִם־הַגֹּלָה אֲשֶׁר הׇגְלְתָה עִם יְכׇנְיָה מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה אֲשֶׁר הֶגְלָה נְבוּכַדְנֶצַּר מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל׃

It sounds like it is talking about Mordechai, but [on sefaria here](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.2.6-7?lang=bi&lookup=%5BKish%5D%20had%20been%20exiled%20from%20Jerusalem%20in%20the%20group%20that%20was%20carried%20into%20exile%20along%20with%20King%20Jeconiah%20of%20Judah%2C%20which%20had%20been%20driven%20into%20exile%20by%20King%20Nebuchadnezzar%20of%20Babylon.&with=Megillah&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%5BKish%5D%20had%20been,7)it says its referring to Kish.

Furthermore, [the Gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Esther.2.6?lang=bi&with=Megillah&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%C2%A7%20The%20Gemara%20resumes,of%20his%20people) seems to insinuate that it is indeed about mordechai.

Comment: The verse is indeed ambiguous and has been interpreted both ways. Not sure what you are looking for exactly since we aren't exactly about to "paskin" this.

Comment: @DoubleAA Unfortunately my knowledge of the jewish historical timeline is not very good. I am trying to pinpoint the timeline between the destruction of the first beis hamikdash and the beginning of the purim story. Was the exiling of mordechai by nebuchadnezzar related to the events of the destruction of bayis rishon? Unfortunately, jewish history is not my strong point...from my reading, the destruction had been only 57 years prior to purim story - is that really accurate?

Answer (score 2):

"who had been exiled" is referring to Mordechai not Kish. Kish is another name for Gera (see [Targum](https://www.sefaria.org/Aramaic%20Targum%20to%20Esther%202:5)). Shimi ben Gera was in King David's time (See [2 Samuel 16:5](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.16.5)).

Comment: R Sadya gaon holds that it is not the same shimi, but a descendant with the same name. The Targum Sheni also traces mordechai’s lineage back to Binyamin in and has a shimi as Mordechai‘s grandfather, many generations after Shaul. Although note that while Targum sheni does not include shimi ben gera in the list of descendants, he does later say that David spared shimi’s life because he saw Mordechai would descend from him

Answer (score 1):

On the verse, in the [Sefer Dvar Yeshua](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6048&st=&pgnum=41&hilite=), a commentary on Megillah by [Netanel Chaim Pappa](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%A2), he says that were it not for the fact that the Talmud clearly says that it is referring to Mordechai (making him really old), he would say that it was referring to Kish, Mordechai’s grandfather.

As you can see in footnote 388 from Otzar Mefarshei Hamegilla on the verse, apparently this idea is also brought in the Sefer yuchsin of rabbi Avraham zacut, introduction to the biur chadash of Yosef Zechariah stern, and Kadmoniyot of rabbi Aharon Marcos. I didn’t look up any of those sources.

[image: see footnote 388 from otzar mefarshei hamegilla on the verse]